# Internet Explorer Nested Form Post

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm am using ASP.NET MVC to create a page that posts to the Paypal sandbox. My form that posts to the Paypal site is nested inside a parent form. I am using Internet Explorer 7, and for some reason, the nested form posts to my local machine instead of the paypal site. If I add a copy of the same nested form directly after the first, the first one posts to localhost, and the second posts to where it is expected.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <title>
    </title>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="aspnetForm" method="post" action="" id="aspnetForm">        
        <!--First form posts locally-->
        <form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
            <input type="submit" value="Pay"/>
        </form>     

        <!--Second identical form posts to the expected destination-->
        <form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">     
            <input type="submit" value="Pay"/>
        </form> 
    </form>
```

Comment: You aren't allowed to nest forms in HTML. Trying to do so just leads to pain as browsers attempt to recover from your error. So don't try.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Nested forms are not vaild, and therefore their behavior is undefined. You just cannot nest them. Only one form can submit at a time, though you can have multiple, unnested forms on a page (only the one of the corresponding submit button will be submitted, though).

Answer (score 3):

Looks like I used the ASP.NET master page template instead of the ASP.NET MVC one. The ASP.NET template includes a form tag which is what created this nested form page. Using the ASP.NET MVC template fixed my problem by removing the nested forms altogether.

Comment: This was the most helpful comment of several posts addressing this issue on stackoverflow!!

Answer (score 0):

Handle the button click event on the server side and post to the site from there.  Nested forms are invalid xhtml.